# what's the utility of `as` operator in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I saw it used in the following instruction:

```
const htmlInput: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById('htmlInput') as HTMLInputElement;
```

The type assertion is already done with `const htmlInput: HTMLInputElement`, so why is `as` operator used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an object of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

The class `Element` is more generic than class [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) and an object of type `Element` does not have all the properties of an object of type `HTMLInputElement`.
The TypeScript compiler complains and does not allow the assignment.

`const htmlInput: HTMLInputElement` is not a type assertion, it is a declaration.
And it is the source of the mismatch.

Here comes the `as` keyword that introduces a [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). A type assertion allows the developer to tell the TS compiler *"trust me, I know what I’m doing."*